# Why does globalizing an array decrease performance?

Tags: php, global

Let me begin by stating that I know using global variables is not the best practice, this is just a temporary tweak until a more extensive rewrite is completed. That said...

I came across some code that was being duplicated 3 times, like so.

template_1 loads an array, then filters out data, then loads template_part_2. template_part_2 loads the array again and filters out the exact same data, then loads the module_1. module_1 loads the array again and filters out the exact same data as the last two. Resulting in something like this:

include_array.php

```
    function load_array(){ 
        <multidimensional array here>
    };
```

template_1.php

```
    include_once(include_array.php);
    $array = load_array();
    // code to filter array
    include_once(template_1_part_2.php);
```

template_1_part_2.php

```
    $array = load_array();
    // code to filter array
    include_once(module_1.php);
```

module_1.php

```
    $array = load_array();
    // code to filter array
```

This seemed unnecessary to me and a waste of memory, so I changed it to only filter once and then globalize it in the subsequent files like so:

include_array.php

```
    function load_array(){ 
        <multidimensional array here>
    };
```

template_1.php

```
    include_once(include_array.php);
    $array = load_array();
    // code to filter array
    include_once(template_1_part_2.php);
```

template_1_part_2.php

```
    global $array;
    include_once(module_1.php);
```

module_1.php

```
    global $array;
```

Now this change saves me 2mb of memory per page load, but the page loads .03 seconds slower. That's about 18% less memory, but loads about 25% slower. I would assume it be more memory efficient and faster since it's doing less processing, but that is not what I'm seeing. I've tried to do some research as to why this is the case but I haven't found anything, can anyone shed some light on this mystery?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As @developerwjk estated, you shouldn't need to redeclare or use `global` at all to make `$array` propagate to all includes. Also, 30 milliseconds seems to be inside the performance fluctuation that ocurs depending on what else is running in the server at that particular time. Are you sure this performance drop is constant?

Comment: @developerwjk is right. The module include is actually being included via a function, and that is where I am losing scope. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't understand how including a file works in PHP.  Basically when you include a file its like the code just gets appended to the one doing the include.  Any variable that's defined outside of all functions is automatically accessible to the code (that's outside all functions) from all the files.  So only inside functions would you have to use the `global` keyword to gain access to a global variable.  You don't use the `global` keyword to make a variable from one file accessible in other files: you included the files all into one already so you don't have to do anything special to let them share.

The [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) say it like:

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable
>   scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available
>   at that line in the calling file will be available within the called
>   file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes
>   defined in the included file have the global scope.

However:

> If the include occurs inside a function within the calling file, then
>   all of the code contained in the called file will behave as though it
>   had been defined inside that function.

Make your includes global, i.e. outside all functions, and you shouldn't have to jump through all these hoops.